# For each value in column 1 get the value for column 3 based on the maximum value in column 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table (also includes table with expected output):

```
CREATE TABLE a
    (brand varchar(1), model varchar(7), activity_day int, week int, month varchar(3), metric int)
;
    
INSERT INTO a
    (brand, model, activity_day, week, month`, metric)
VALUES
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200101, 1, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200102, 1, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200103, 1, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200104, 1, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200105, 2, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200106, 2, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200107, 2, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200108, 2, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200109, 2, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200110, 2, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200111, 2, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200112, 3, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200113, 3, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200114, 3, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200115, 3, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200116, 3, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200117, 3, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200118, 3, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200119, 4, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200120, 4, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200121, 4, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200122, 4, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200123, 4, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200124, 4, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200126, 5, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200127, 5, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200128, 5, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200129, 5, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200130, 5, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200131, 5, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200101, 1, 'Jan', 3695.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200101, 1, 'Jan', 578.01),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200102, 1, 'Jan', 3695.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200102, 1, 'Jan', 578.08),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200103, 1, 'Jan', 481.87),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200103, 1, 'Jan', 3791.21),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200104, 1, 'Jan', 481.87),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200104, 1, 'Jan', 3839.2),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200105, 2, 'Jan', 3791.21),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200105, 2, 'Jan', 529.86),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200106, 2, 'Jan', 432.5),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200106, 2, 'Jan', 3791.21),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200107, 2, 'Jan', 144.42),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200107, 2, 'Jan', 3695.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200108, 2, 'Jan', 3647.24),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200108, 2, 'Jan', 48.31),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200109, 2, 'Jan', 3599.25),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200109, 2, 'Jan', 144.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200110, 2, 'Jan', 48.27),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200110, 2, 'Jan', 3599.25),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200111, 2, 'Jan', 3551.26),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200111, 2, 'Jan', 48.27),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200112, 3, 'Jan', 48.27),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200112, 3, 'Jan', 3551.26),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200113, 3, 'Jan', 3551.26),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200113, 3, 'Jan', 48.25),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200114, 3, 'Jan', 3455.28),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200114, 3, 'Jan', 48.22),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200115, 3, 'Jan', 3503.27),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200115, 3, 'Jan', 48.3),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200116, 3, 'Jan', 48.3),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200116, 3, 'Jan', 3455.28),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200117, 3, 'Jan', 3407.29),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200117, 3, 'Jan', 96.2),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200118, 3, 'Jan', 3359.3),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200118, 3, 'Jan', 96.2),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200119, 4, 'Jan', 2351.51),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200119, 4, 'Jan', 96.2),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200120, 4, 'Jan', 2303.52),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200120, 4, 'Jan', 96.27),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200121, 4, 'Jan', 2303.52),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200121, 4, 'Jan', 48.19),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200122, 4, 'Jan', 47.96),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200122, 4, 'Jan', 3167.34),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200123, 4, 'Jan', 3071.36),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200124, 4, 'Jan', 3071.36),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200125, 4, 'Jan', 3071.36),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200126, 5, 'Jan', 2975.38),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200127, 5, 'Jan', 2975.38),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200128, 5, 'Jan', 3023.37),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200129, 5, 'Jan', 3023.37),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200130, 5, 'Jan', 3023.37),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200131, 5, 'Jan', 3023.37),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200101, 1, 'Jan', 1239.24),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200101, 1, 'Jan', 46233.13),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200102, 1, 'Jan', 1241.85),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200102, 1, 'Jan', 45009.22),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200103, 1, 'Jan', 40744.53),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200103, 1, 'Jan', 1182.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200104, 1, 'Jan', 1182.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200104, 1, 'Jan', 36489.29),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200105, 2, 'Jan', 1182.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200105, 2, 'Jan', 35649.44),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200106, 2, 'Jan', 28603.82),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200106, 2, 'Jan', 1241.67),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200107, 2, 'Jan', 1126.22),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200107, 2, 'Jan', 25796.89),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200108, 2, 'Jan', 1017.18),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200108, 2, 'Jan', 24295.25),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200109, 2, 'Jan', 1016.13),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200109, 2, 'Jan', 23116.43),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200110, 2, 'Jan', 22058.34),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200110, 2, 'Jan', 1018.09),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200111, 2, 'Jan', 19594.78),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200111, 2, 'Jan', 1018.09),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200112, 3, 'Jan', 23121.84),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200112, 3, 'Jan', 1018.09),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200113, 3, 'Jan', 1017.45),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200113, 3, 'Jan', 10466.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200114, 3, 'Jan', 1018.67),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200114, 3, 'Jan', 11589.48),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200115, 3, 'Jan', 1018.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200115, 3, 'Jan', 13323.88),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200116, 3, 'Jan', 22843.26),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200116, 3, 'Jan', 1018.6),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200117, 3, 'Jan', 1024.21),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200117, 3, 'Jan', 19220.15),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200118, 3, 'Jan', 1024.21),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200118, 3, 'Jan', 39152.59),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200119, 4, 'Jan', 36689.03),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200119, 4, 'Jan', 1024.21),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200120, 4, 'Jan', 1024.08),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200120, 4, 'Jan', 33049.3),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200121, 4, 'Jan', 25364.17),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200121, 4, 'Jan', 962.26),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200122, 4, 'Jan', 21680),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200122, 4, 'Jan', 909.87),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200123, 4, 'Jan', 962.51),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200123, 4, 'Jan', 25924.86),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200124, 4, 'Jan', 27490.18),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200124, 4, 'Jan', 961.74),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200125, 4, 'Jan', 961.74),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200125, 4, 'Jan', 39919.96),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200126, 5, 'Jan', 905.75),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200126, 5, 'Jan', 37568.38),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200127, 5, 'Jan', 900.45),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200127, 5, 'Jan', 36712.09),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200128, 5, 'Jan', 39088.32),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200128, 5, 'Jan', 908.43),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200129, 5, 'Jan', 38586.63),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200129, 5, 'Jan', 909.26),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200130, 5, 'Jan', 42496.02),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200130, 5, 'Jan', 906),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200131, 5, 'Jan', 38736.06),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200131, 5, 'Jan', 903.26)
;


CREATE TABLE expected_table
    (brand varchar(1), model varchar(7), activity_day int, week int, month varchar(3), metric numeric)
;
    
INSERT INTO expected_table
    (brand, model, activity_day, week, month, metric)
VALUES
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200104, 1, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200111, 2, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200118, 3, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200124, 4, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'model_1', 20200131, 5, 'Jan', 459.95),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200104, 1, 'Jan', 481.87),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200111, 2, 'Jan', 48.27),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200118, 3, 'Jan', 96.2),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200125, 4, 'Jan', 3071.36),
    ('A', 'MODEL_2', 20200131, 5, 'Jan', 3023.37),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200104, 1, 'Jan', 1182.23),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200111, 2, 'Jan', 1018.09),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200118, 3, 'Jan', 1024.21),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200125, 4, 'Jan', 961.74),
    ('A', 'MODEL_3', 20200131, 5, 'Jan', 903.26)
;
```

The date is in format YYYYMMDD.

I want to achieve a table where it shows the metric for each week for each model number, but the problem that I've been stuck on is that I want to get the latest metric value only depending on the date if the week is the same. There are some scenarios where the date and the week number is the same, but the metric is different, and if that is the case then I want the minimum metric between those. I get close to the result when I do `MAX` on activity day and `GROUP BY` on the rest of the columns, but this fails when the metric changes within the same week.

I am new to SQL and have heard that you should really trying to avoid using loops, so I am having a hard time adjusting to this type of thinking.

Comment: And please show your expected results for the given sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by activity_day desc, metric asc

```
;with exp_cte as (
    select a.*, row_number() over (partition by [week], model order by activity_day desc, metric asc) rn from a a)
select * from exp_cte
where rn=1
order by 2,3;
```

Results

```
brand   model   activity_day    week    month   metric  rn
A       model_1 20200104        1      Jan      459     1
A       model_1 20200111        2      Jan      459     1
A       model_1 20200118        3      Jan      459     1
A       model_1 20200124        4      Jan      459     1
A       model_1 20200131        5      Jan      459     1
A       MODEL_2 20200104        1      Jan      481     1
A       MODEL_2 20200111        2      Jan      48      1
A       MODEL_2 20200118        3      Jan      96      1
A       MODEL_2 20200125        4      Jan      3071    1
A       MODEL_2 20200131        5      Jan      3023    1
A       MODEL_3 20200104        1      Jan      1182    1
A       MODEL_3 20200111        2      Jan      1018    1
A       MODEL_3 20200118        3      Jan      1024    1
A       MODEL_3 20200125        4      Jan      961     1
A       MODEL_3 20200131        5      Jan      903     1
```

Answer (score 4):

I *think* you just want `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by week, model
                                order by activity_date desc, metric desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There was also another point that I had in the main post: There are some scenarios where the date and the week number is the same, but the metric is different, and if that is the case then I want the minimum metric between those. Any way to incorporate that also?

Comment: That is why there is a second key in the `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
insert expected_table
select a.*
from ( select brand            = a.brand ,           
              model            = a.model ,
              week             = a.week  ,
              max_activity_day = max( a.activity_day )
       from a
       group by a.brand,
                a.model,
                a.week,
                max( a. activity_day )
     ) t1
join a on a.brand        = t1.brand,
          a.model        = t1.model,
          a.week         = t1.week,
          a.activity_day = t1.max_activity_day
```